# How do I zoom in using the App version of Twine?

Tags: interface, twine

[image]

How do I zoom in using this program in Windows 10?

Comment: Hi watercollider. Have you tried searching online about a tutorial for basic controls for `Twine` ? Maybe on some forums dedicated about that program?

Comment: Yes, I googled it and opened the help guide in Twine, thanks.

Comment: @watercollider Please keep in mind that users are here to help. And that the down arrow below the question score says "does not show any research effort". Sometimes these users willing to help will try to make sure you did try to fix the issue yourself before clicking that down arrow. [gamedev.se] is more forgiving than [SO]. (I removed the rant part of your comment.)

Comment: Actually, I'd like to apologize. It's the holidays and I have been VERY stressed lately. I did not mean to snap like that. It wasn't earned.